# Launching React Native app opens up chrome browser at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/

Tags: react-native

Somehow from today when launching react native 0.62.3 app in VS code, it automatically open up chrome browser at `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/` instead of launching app on Android emulator. There is no chrome debugger tool installed (removed). Removed the `node_modules` and reinstall. The problem is the same. How to stop this annoying behavior?

[image]

Here is the android emulator screen:

[image]

Here is the error on console screen:

```
[Sat Apr 10 2021 23:47:02.410]  LOG      JavaScript logs will appear in your browser console
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639` from ``:

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.cff11639(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.cff11639\index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\D\code\js\xyz_app3\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\D\code\js\xyz_app3\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\D\code\js\xyz_app3\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at C:\D\code\js\xyz_app3\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at C:\D\code\js\xyz_app3\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1096:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\D\code\js\xyz_app3\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (C:\D\code\js\xyz_app3\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28844  Here is a similar issue reported with react native. But none of solutions works here.